# Android Self-modifying code - NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, self-modifying

I am trying to make a self-modifying code library and I have scowered all over and I have the follow code:

```
typedef int (*FUNC) (void);
int test();

JNIEXPORT int Java_com_example_untitled_MyActivity_decrypt( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
{
    void *code = mmap(NULL, 4, PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    if (code != MAP_FAILED) {
        memcpy(code, test, 4);

        return ( (FUNC)code)();
    }

    return 0;
}

int test()
{
    return 100;
}
```

Please help...I used [Native self-modifying code on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461609/native-self-modifying-code-on-android) as my starting point and they said something about compiling with "-marm" and thumb bit...

My issue I'm having is, it's just crashing. I have tried using the cacheflush function, didn't seem to help. I am at a loss.

Comment: What problem are you having? What is the expected behavior and observed behavior of your code? (For example, why do you think that test is exactly 4 bytes long?)

Comment: Because I reverse engineer ARM and know that mov r0,100 is 2 bytes and BX LR is 2 bytes...:) Also verified it's not using the 4 byte mov instruction.

Comment: ARM instructions are 4 bytes in length...

Comment: No, not always. I checked with IDA and they are only 2 bytes each instruction. I reverse engineer Android games and have modified over 100 of them in ARM, using both 2 and 4 byte instructions.

Comment: Sounds like Thumb, not ARM, to me. To call from Thumb to ARM, or ARM to Thumb, requires an instruction set exchange (BLX instead of BL). A two-byte BX LR instruction is a return from thumb code to ARM; but the caller needs to know to call in with a mode change (or just stick with ARM and make it simple).

Comment: Yea, they mentioned that! I know the instruction set but not that well. Anyway to tell NDK to use only ARM?

Comment: -marm, as you mention. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380152/android-ndk-does-it-support-straight-arm-code-or-just-thumb

Comment: I tried ./ndk-build -marm and it didn't work, do I need to edit the .mk file?

Answer (score 0):

On ARM, you need to flush the CPU caches in order to ensure that the instructions you just copied are visible to the CPU before they are executed. A simple way to do this is:

```
#include <unistd.h>  // for cacheflush()

...

// Copy the instructions to the destination address.
memcpy(dest, original_intructions, size_of_instructions);

// Clear the CPU cache
cacheflush((uintptr_t)dest, (uintptr_t)dest + size_of_instructions, 0);

// Run them.
return ((FUNC)dest)();
```

Comment: That was not the issue directly. The issue was as addaon stated. Maybe you can answer me this though, Could I compile a function, take the ARM, remove the function and still use the ARM and pass paramaters to it? Or does ARM use memory addresses that would cause an issue?

Comment: It depends on how the function was compiled. You would need to use -fPIC first to generate position-independent code. Second, you need to ensure that the function never tries to access a global variable, or another function (both introduce relocations that prevent doing what you want).

Comment: I ended up just modifying the memory of the application using mprotect, so the code is just obfuscated in ida, using AES and multilevel obfuscation.