# Can I write Android app that overwrites itself?

Tags: android, apk, self-modifying

Regardless of publishability, is it possible write an android Java application that at some point, while running, overwrites itself with some other random code and restarts itself? Does it remain an executable application after the change? Where can I look for resources on how to do this?

Clarifying, let's suppose I have a brand new Foo app, and somewhere in there I have a method,

```
// yes I know, it's just an example
public static int getOne(){
  return 1;
}
```

And at some point in the execution of the application, I want it to change getOne() to now do

```
// again, not the most useful example, but an example nonetheless
public static double getOne(){
  return OtherModule.getTwo();
}
```

And then somehow rebuild the app, live, so that everything just uses this new method?

Thanks!

Comment: I read many times and couldn't understand what you want to dude!

Comment: I don't think he wants to dude anything.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: I clarified a bit. Is that something that can be done?

Comment: @tachyonflux can the app issue those itself on itself?

Comment: The only material I've seen on the subject is native code using the NDK - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176037/android-self-modifying-code-ndk

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not totally sure and it is not generally a good practice, but I guess you are referring to dynamically loading classes. If so, please see:
[How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)